# Replace all the id values with another set of ids in a body request in Javascript

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-pre-request-script

I have one response and I have one request:

1. Response

```
{
  "questions": [
    {
      "id": 75930,
      "drmsCaseId": 236,
      "questionId": 32,
      "answer": "",
      "questionGroup": {
        "key": "KYC",
        "value": "Know Your Client Check",
        "sortingOrder": 4,
        "integrValue": ""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

2. Request

```
{
  "answers": [
    { "id": 60000, "answer": "fsd" },
    { "id": 60001, "answer": "fds" },
    { "id": 60002, "answer": "fds" },
    { "id": 60004, "answer": "No" }
  ]
}
```

What I want to do is replace all id values in request from the ones I get in response. Any help would b greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the relation between id in both request and response. YOur questions is really unclear

Comment: the point is I want to just reuse the answers for the new questions with new ids which are generated sequentially every time there is a new set of questions opened in Response body

Comment: It would be better to show an expected result, I still find it unclear.

Comment: Expected result is to have all the ids from 1. Response in 2 Request:  for example: answers: “id”:75930